# Linear Algebra: Systems of Differential Equations Proof

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\lambda$ = $\alpha$ + *ib* (where *b* is not 0) be an eigenvalue of the *n* x *n* real matrix **A** with corresponding eigenvector **v** = **r** + *i***s**. We have shown that two real-valued solutions to **x**' = **Ax** are

$x_1$(t) = $e^{at}$[cos *bt* **r** - sin *bt* **s**]

$x_2$(t) = $e^{at}$[sin *bt* **r** + cos *bt* **s**]

Prove that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent on any interval. You may assume that **r** and **s** are linearly independent in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ {\rm det}\ [x_1\ x_2] = e^{2at}{\rm det} [(\cos\ bt{\bf r} - \sin\ bt{\bf s})\
  (\sin\ bt{\bf r} + \cos\ bt{\bf s})]
$$
$$ {\rm det}\ \cos\ bt\sin\ bt[x_1\ x_2] = e^{2at}{\rm det}[\sin\ bt(\cos\ bt{\bf r} - \sin\ bt{\bf s})\
  \cos\ bt(\sin\ bt{\bf r} + \cos\ bt{\bf s})]=
e^{2at}{\rm det} [\sin\ bt(\cos\ bt{\bf r} - \sin\ bt{\bf s})\
  {\bf s}] $$

$$ {\rm det}\ \cos\ bt[x_1\ x_2] = e^{2at}{\rm det} [(\cos\ bt{\bf r} - \sin\ bt{\bf s})\
 {\bf s}]  = e^{2at}{\rm det} [\cos\ bt{\bf r}\
 {\bf s}]$$ so that $${\rm det}[x_1\ x_2]=e^{2at}{\rm det}\ [{\bf r} \ {\bf s}]$$